# Deciding if a set of hyperplanes passes through a point

Tags: computational-complexity

There is a set of vectors $\vec a_{k,i}$ with $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $i\in\{0,1\}$,
such that every $n+1$-tuple $\{\vec v_{1,s_1},\dots,\vec v_{n,s_n},\vec v_{r,1-s_r}\}$
is linearly independent for every $\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}\equiv\vec s\in\{0,1\}^n$ and every $r\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. The whole set spans a $n+1$-dimensional space.
Given another vector $\vec w$, the problem is to decide if there is an $\vec s\in\{0,1\}^n$
such that $\vec w$ is in the span of the vectors $\vec v_{1,s_1},\dots,\vec v_{n,s_n}$.
The problem is clearly $NP$. Is it also $P$?